# How to Run Excel VBA Macros only for sometime

Tags: excel, vba

I have developed a excel macro which checks the particular directory for a File, if there is a matching file it will pick and execute the macro, my point is I want to check the directory only for 5mins if the file is created/appears in the mentioned directory it should pick and process, if not throw an error. How to run macro only for a particular time.

```
Do

    If fso.FileExists("file") Then

        Exit Do
    End If

    DoEvents 'Prevents Excel from being unresponsive
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01") 'wait for one second
Loop

MsgBox "file available"
```

Comment: You want this macro to run in a loop checking every 1 second until it hits the 5 minute mark, where it exits with a message box? Before your loop starts, capture the current time in a variable. Each loop, check that variable to see if it's 5 minutes later. If it is, exit the loop.

Comment: Hi @JNevill thanks for your reply....So Basically lets take an example like -> My macro should run from current time +5 mins and stop. How is it to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, please. It wait 10 seconds. It is easy to be adapted at what you need.

```
Sub testFiniteLoop()
 Dim start As Date, fso As Object, fileName As String, boolFound As Boolean

 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 fileName = "C:\test.txt" ' use here your full file name
 start = Now
 Do While Now <= start + TimeValue("00:00:10")' use here what time you need

    If fso.FileExists(fileName) Then
        boolFound = True
        Exit Do
    End If

    DoEvents 'Prevents Excel from being unresponsive
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01") 'wait for one second
 Loop

 MsgBox IIf(boolFound, "File available", "Checking time passed")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a typical way to wait for an event for a limited period of time:

```
Sub DualCriteria()
    Dim tStart As Date, tNow As Date
    msg = ""
    tStart = Now

    Do
        DoEvents
        If Range("A1").Value <> "" Then
            msg = "event occured"
            Exit Do
        End If
        tNow = Now
        If tNow - tStart > TimeSerial(0, 5, 0) Then
            msg = "timeout"
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

  MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

The macro waits for the User to put a value in cell **A1**.  If nothing happens for 5 minutes the loop exits anyway.

A message tells you why the loop ended.

**NOTE:**

The `Doevents` allows focus to be shared with worksheet activities.